# ActionBarSherlock: Show and Hide the ActionBar + StatusBar

Tags: hide, actionbarsherlock, statusbar

I am currentlky trying to hide and show my application in Fullscreen.
I started a new FullScreenActivity according to the Eclipse templates.

This is the code I use to show / Hide the ActionBar + NotificationBar

```
public void hide() {
    if ((mFlags & FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0) {
        mActivity.getSupportActionBar().hide();
        mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    }
    mOnVisibilityChangeListener.onVisibilityChange(false);
    mVisible = false;
}

public void show() {
    if ((mFlags & FLAG_FULLSCREEN) != 0) {
        mActivity.getSupportActionBar().show();         
        mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(0,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);            
    }
    mOnVisibilityChangeListener.onVisibilityChange(true);
    mVisible = true;
}
```

It kinda work but my big issue is that the ActionBar is overlapped by notifications:

[image]

Any idea on what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Self answer:

I had to remove these lines that were automatically generated in the template:

```
    if ((mFlags & FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN_OLDER_DEVICES) == 0) {
        mActivity.getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                        | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS);
    }
```